# How to create a list of variable names to some function of that variable

Tags: functional-style

For example, for a single variable I can write

```
Print[Unevaluated[a], "=", f[a]]
```

But if I try the next thing I'd think of doing, assuming I want a list, it doesn't work (as intended):

```
Print[Unevaluated[#], "=", f[#]] & /@ {a, b, c}
```

This will print the actual value of `a`, instead of "a" itself (i.e. the variable name.) Any thoughts how I can achieve this?

-- Edit:

To be perfectly clear, I want something like:

```
{{"a", f[a]}, {"b", f[b]}, ...}
```

as the output. It tentatively seems to me that this just simply isn't possible (without putting a Hold or similar on every single thing in the list ...), but I hope I'm wrong.

-- Another edit:

Thanks for the comments; I've almost been able to do what I need. Here's the essential code:

```
{ SymbolName@Unevaluated[#] & /@ Unevaluated /@ Unevaluated@#1,
  Distribute[f[#1, #2], List]} & @@ 
  Unevaluated /@ Unevaluated@{{x, b, c}, {x, y}}
```

with output

```
{{x,b,c},{f(2,2),f(2,y),f(b,2),f(b,y),f(c,2),f(c,y)}}
```

Note that I'm only able to print "{x, b, c}" here. I actually would like a tree; i.e.,

```
{{x,{x,y}},{b,{x,y},{c,{x,y}}, {f(...), ...}
```

or something that is equivalent in letting my match the input to the output ..., any thoughts? I'm trying this myself but I keep getting stuck with how Unevaluated treats parameters ... (i.e. it's not listable; and Distribute seems to require that, in order to work in the expected way...)

(I should note, the only reason I want that tree form is because getting the exact form I asked for initially within the confines of the Distribute and so on seems harder (I couldn't work it out ...).) I don't actually care how it comes out, as long as I can Partition or whatever to get the appropriate structure.

-- Final edit:

Just incase anyone is interested, here is what I finally went with; it may not be amazingly elegant, but it's sufficient for what I needed. Note that it's actually neccessary to duplicate the expressions into the `Unevaluated` calls (afaik).

```
fMap = Flatten[Outer[f[#1, #2], A, B, 1]];
n1 = SymbolName@Unevaluated[#] & /@ 
   Unevaluated /@ Unevaluated[{x, b, c, d}];
n2 = SymbolName@Unevaluated[#] & /@ 
   Unevaluated /@ Unevaluated[{x, y, z}];
```

I can then create the listing I wanted via

```
Grid[{
    grid1 = 
     Flatten@Insert[n1, ConstantArray["", Length@n2 - 1], 
       Table[{i + 1}, {i, Range[Length@n1]}]],
    grid2 = Flatten@ConstantArray[n2, Length@n1],
    fMap
    }\[Transpose], Frame -> All];
```

Comment: I am sure what your purpose is but.. `Print[ToString[#] <> "=" <> ToString[f[#]]] & /@ {a, b, c};`

Comment: @chris, try executing `{a, b, c} = Range[3]` before that.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to do `Set[f[#], #] & /@ {a, b, c};` instead?

Comment: @J.M right; on the other hand what does `1=f[1]` mean? Should it be `1==f[1]` ?

Comment: @chris, I suppose OP should try to talk about what he wants to actually do...

Comment: I meant "I am not sure what your purpose"...

Comment: chris/J. M. - I think it's clear from the title. I want the variable name and the function of that variable in a list. You can see this if you run the first example, compared to the second, with J.M.s values for `a,b,c`. The example here just captures the essential idea; of course "x = f(x)" where f(x) is evaluated doesn't mean much. It's just text.

Comment: @NoonSilk well if your purpose is only printing my first suggestion does just that. Otherwise you could use Equal rather than set; finally english is not my native language but it does not seem to me the title makes much sense.

Comment: @chris - Thanks for your help but your first suggestion doesn't work. Please try putting `{a, b, c} = Range[3]` beforehand, and run the two statements in my original post. You will see the difference. The first output is right, the second is "wrong" (i.e. not what I want). I want the first, but I want to supply a list. (Note that your attempt doesn't work in either form; list or direct variable use.)

Comment: Does `Print[#, "=", f[#]] & /@ Defer /@ Unevaluated@{a, b, c}` or `Print[#, "=", f[#]] & /@ HoldForm/@ Unevaluated@{a, b, c}` work for what you are trying to do? Or, `Print[Unevaluated@#, "=", Unevaluated@f[#]] & /@ Unevaluated /@ Unevaluated@{a, b, c}`?:)

Comment: or Print[Unevaluated@#, "=", f[#]] & /@ 
 Unevaluated /@ Unevaluated@{a, b, c} following kguler? This seems to do the same as your original statement.

Comment: @NoonSilk I suggest changing create to assign in your title?

Comment: Haha! Yes, @kguler the second one does, with `ReleaseHold` like so `f[ReleaseHold[#]]`. Awesome! Thanks!

Comment: ...or `Print[ToString[#], "=", f[#]] & /@ HoldForm /@ Unevaluated@{a, b, c}`??

Comment: @chris Thanks! That also works! Sorry for the title not being clear.

Comment: I discussed `Unevaluated` in some detail in my post in [this Mathgroup thread](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/bfd67e9122b1fdec/)(my second post there). Some people found that useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Print[{ToString@#, f @@ #}] & /@ HoldForm /@ Unevaluated@{a, b, c}
(* or *)
Print[{ToString@#, f @@ #}] & /@ Defer/@ Unevaluated@{a, b, c}
```

to get

```
{"a", f[1]}
{"b", f[2]}
{"c", f[3]}
```

printed. Remove `Print`, i.e. use `{ToString@#, f @@ #} & /@ HoldForm /@ Unevaluated@{a, b, c}` to get `{{"a", f[1]}, {"b", f[2]}, {"c", f[3]}}`.

To get `{"a", f[a]}  {"b", f[a]}  {"c", f[a]}`, change `f@@#` to `f@#`.

Comment: Accepting this because it answers what I originally asked. Note that I've added an extra little bit to the question now, though :)

Comment: @NoonSilk, thank you for the accept. I think it may be useful to treat the two parts in the new "bit" (constructing a tree and managing evaluation of symbols with assigned values) separately and combine them later. For the second part, it may be useful to update your question with information on which symbols have assigned values.

Comment: You're right; doing everything seperately has worked. I think it also makes more sense this way. Thanks!

Comment: Hahaha, it turns out, this *doesn't* work, if instead of the list I have a variable containing the list ..., i.e. `A = {a,b,c}; Print[{ToString@#, f @@ #}] & /@ HoldForm /@ Unevaluated@A;` ... how strange.

Comment: @NoonSilk, this should not be surprising: note that once you set `A={a,b,c}`, `A` has the value `{1,2,3}`. Stuff you do with `A` after your initial assignment will not remember the symbols `a, b, c`. To get `{"A",f[A]}` you can simply use `{ToString@#, f@#} &@HoldForm@A` or to get `{"A",f[{1,2,3}]}` use `{ToString@#, f @@ #} &@HoldForm@A`. Note the use of `@` before `A` as opposed to `/@` (`Map`) which gets inside `A` and finds `1,2,3`.

Comment: Yeah. That's why I was kind of thinking it was impossible. Shame, because it means I have to duplicate some expressions. But I think it's the best I'm going to get.

Answer (score 1):

Literally following what you've suggested you need as output:

> {{"a", f[a]}, {"b", f[b]}, ...}

i.e. A list containing the string form name of a variable and the application of function `f` to that variable we get:

```
{SymbolName@#, HoldForm@f[#]} & /@ {a, b, c}
```

> {{"a", f[a]}, {"b", f[b]}, {"c", f[c]}}

I hope this was what you wanted.

Comment: Following on from @kguler and @chris, it is actually: `{SymbolName@Unevaluated[#], f[#]} & /@ 
 Unevaluated /@ Unevaluated@{a, b, c}`. Your version (as-is) has the same problem as the ealier ones; with apparently not enough `Unevaluated`'s :)

Comment: Apologies, I didn't pick that up from the output line, now fixed, no `Unevaluated` needed.